# R, Merging duplicate rows filling incomplete data

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge duplicates in this data frame in R

```
first last  city    in   out   
john  doe   sf      1    0
mary  jane  cl      NA   NA 
john  doe   NA      NA   NA
mary  jane  NA      1    0 
john  shmo  dn      1    0
```

to this result

```
john  doe   sf    1    0
mary  jane  cl    1    0 
john  shmo  dn    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `fill` the `NA` values for each name and keep only the unique rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(first, last) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = 'updown') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct()

#  first last  city     IN   out
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#1 john  doe   sf        1     0
#2 mary  jane  cl        1     0
#3 john  shmo  dn        1     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(first = c("john", "mary", "john", "mary", "john"
), last = c("doe", "jane", "doe", "jane", "shmo"), city = c("sf", 
"cl", NA, NA, "dn"), IN = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), out = c(0L, 
NA, NA, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. I collapsed the columns while removing NAs.

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- read.table(
  text = "
  first last  city   in out   
john  doe   sf      1    0
mary  jane  cl      NA   NA 
john  doe   NA      NA   NA
mary  jane  NA      1    0 
john  shmo  dn      1    0
  ", header = TRUE
)

dat1 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(first, last) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(city:out, ~.[!is.na(.)])
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

dat1

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   first last  city    in.   out
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 john  doe   sf        1     0
# 2 john  shmo  dn        1     0
# 3 mary  jane  cl        1     0
```